# Is there a difference in creating tables with csv vs. from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, databricks

I created a table using the code below in Microsoft Azure Databricks (However, I think this translates across any sql environment):

```
CREATE TABLE employee_data_csv (
column1,
column2,
column3 )
USING csv
OPTIONS (path "C:/pathway/xxxx", header "true", mode "FAILFAST")
```

I was told that creating the table with `USING csv` method can affect performance. It was suggested that I use the table created above and create another table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_data
Select column1, column2, column3
FROM employee_data_csv
```

I did not notice any speed improvements. Is there any performance change between these two tables or approaches? Is the second step necessary?

Comment: Ok, I have never seen SQL Server and a USING clause. Is this valid SQL Server syntax? Or specific to Databricks? I'm curious. But I am guessing that querying a CSV from Azure means the potential for much more latency than having the engine derive the table structure from another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is in CSV, you'll need to provide the format as you did when you created the table.

The CTAS (create table as select) will not translate the underlying format, this is something you would need to provide.

The speed benefit will depend on a few factors. The dataset size, type of query, and cluster size will have an impact on the read performance.

You can run the following SQL cell to verify the format:

```
%sql
desc extended employee_data
```

The `Provider` field will state the file format, e.g. csv in this example.

To convert to parquet, you could run the following:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_data USING PARQUET as 
Select column1, column2, column3
FROM employee_data_csv
```

Comment: By 'format' do you mean data types for each column?

Comment: No, by format I mean the underlying data layout that is supported. See the docs here under "Data Source": https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-table.html Parquet is the recommended format to get better read performance, hence my example above uses parquet in the last example.